# How to pass a single string value into shared preferences when the data has been taken from an Arraylist(converted into a json file)?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

I am currently creating a notes app that has a recycler view. The data is stored in an arraylist named notes. Once an itemholder is clicked, a new activity is opened which contains an edit-text and a save button. Once the save button is pressed, the data that's in the edit-text needs to be saved in the shared preferences. Since it directly can't be saved, how should i proceed?

Here's the code

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList notes = new ArrayList();
ArrayList fakeEmpty = new ArrayList();
Button button1;
Integer n = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    notes = getArrayList("102");
    if (notes == null){
        notes = fakeEmpty;
    }
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    final CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, notes);
    Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            notes.add("note " + n.toString());
            n++;
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            saveArrayList(notes,"102");
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);


}
public void saveArrayList(ArrayList<String> list, String key){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);
    editor.putString(key, json);
    editor.apply();

}

public ArrayList<String> getArrayList(String key){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = prefs.getString(key, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}


public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener;
ArrayList notes;
Context context;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList notes) {
    this.context = context;
    this.notes = notes;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return vh;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.note.setText(notes.get(position).toString());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), NotesView.class);
            intent.putExtra("101", notes.get(position).toString());
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Snackbar.make(v, "Do you wanna delete?", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Delete", mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NotesView.class);
                            intent.putExtra("101", notes.get(position).toString());
                            notes.remove(notes.get(position));
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
            return true;

        }
    });

}

public int getItemCount() {
    if(notes == null){
        return 0;
    }
    else return notes.size();

}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView note;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        note = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.note);
    }
}

public class NotesView extends Activity {
    EditText NotesEditText;
    Button SaveBut;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notesview);
        NotesEditText = findViewById(R.id.NotesEditText);
        final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String text1 = extras.getString("101") ;
        NotesEditText.setText(text1);
        SaveBut = findViewById(R.id.SaveBut);
        SaveBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                extras.putString("101",NotesEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more, what's actually your issue? you want to store `ArrayList` into `Sharedpreference` right?

Comment: **SharedPreferences** stores information in key-value pairs and is only meant store small pieces of data like User preferences. For something like notes application, where you would be storing a quite a bit data you should preferably us **SQLite database**. If you want to use SharePreferences anyway, please add more details as to where exactly you are facing problem and share error log if any.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up passing both the position and the text using intent to the main activity. After passing it, i updated the Arraylist using arraylist.set(position_from_intent,text_from_intent). This was just a workaround and still didnt pass a value directly to the array list.